# What is wrong with this timer?

Tags: java, timer, countdown

I am doing a timer to countdown fro 90 seconds all the way down to zero, however when i run it, it will run for 1 second and terminate, plz help! Point out what is wrong!

```
package TestingFile;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class TestingATimer extends JFrame
{
    private Timer timer;
    public int count = 90;

    public TestingATimer()
    {
        timer = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener());
        timer.start();
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (count != 0)
            {   
            count--;
            System.out.println(count + " seconds elapsed"); 
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        new TestingATimer ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ummm. Perhaps because you have it set to 1000 milliseconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (Swing) `Timer` is likely using a `daemon` based thread.  This means that once the `main` method exists, there is nothing keeping the JVM from terminating...

From the [`Thread` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single
>   non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named main of some
>   designated class). The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute
>   threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> - The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security
>     manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
> - All threads
>     that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the
>     call to the run method or by throwing an exception that propagates
>     beyond the run method.

So there is nothing stopping the JVM from terminating.

The question is, why are you using a `javax.swing.Timer` without a GUI?  What are you trying to achieve?

**Updated**

If you don't want to use a GUI, you will need to use a `java.util.Timer`, for example...

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Clock {

    private static Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TickTask(), 0, 1000);

    }

    public static class TickTask extends TimerTask {

        private boolean started = false;
        private long startTime = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!started) {
                started = true;
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else {
                long dif = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                long seconds = dif / 1000;
                System.out.println(seconds);
                if (seconds >= 90) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Otherwise you'll need to supply some kind GUI...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ClockGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClockGUI();
    }

    public ClockGUI() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Timer timer;
        private JLabel clock;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            clock = new JLabel("...");
            add(clock);
            timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

                private boolean started = false;
                private long startTime = 0;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (!started) {
                        started = true;
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    } else {
                        long dif = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                        long seconds = dif / 1000;
                        clock.setText(Long.toString(seconds));
                        if (seconds >= 90) {
                            timer.stop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: _"The question is, why are you using a javax.swing.Timer without a GUI? What are you trying to achieve?"_ -- **EXACTLY!!**

Answer (score 2):

*" however when i run it, it will run for 1 second and terminate"*

Because you've set it to 1 second (1000 miliseconds) here:

```
timer = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener());
```

If you want 90 seconds then do this:

```
timer = new Timer(90000, new TimerListener());
```

Comment: Nope, it just terminates.

Comment: @user3171151 which part _"nope"_ referring to?

Comment: When, i change it to 90000.

Comment: @user3171151 try using `timer.schedule(new TimerListener(), 90000);` instead

Comment: @RafaEl There is no such method in either `javax.swing.Timer` or `java.util.Timer`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer `TimerListener()` referring to OP's `class`

Comment: Which is an `ActionListener`, `java.util.Timer` requires a `TimerTask` and `javax.swing.Timer` has no such method called `schedule`

Comment: Oh damn, you're right! @user3171151 refer MadProgrammer for a clearer answer.

Comment: It is suppose to be a basic text based game.