# Turning off a button after a few seconds?

Tags: java, timer, timertask

Hey guys I have this coded where I have two images one is of a light bulb that is on and the other is of a light bulb that is turned off. I have two buttons one on and one off. when I press the on button the image of the on bulb appears, when I press the off bulb the picture of the off bulb appears. I who basically an offListener class and an OnListener which turns the bulb off/on and repaints the bulb panel.

Now what I want to do is modify this code using the TIMER class and possibly use TimerTask too. I want to (once the bulb has been turned on) start a countdown of 10 seconds saying in 10 seconds the bulb will turn off and once the displaced time has reached 10 seconds the bulb will repaint the off lightbulb image.

So What I was thinking was importing the Timer and using TimerTask in it. so Would most of my code of modification reside in the OnListener class? would I have to extend it to TaskTimer? I'm sorry this is a bit of a stump for me. I'm just trying to understand it. If anyone has time and is willing to talk this over with me I'd be even more happy, but comments do help please!

```
//********************************************************************
//  LightBulbControls.java      
//
//  Represents the control panel for the LightBulb program.
//********************************************************************

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Timer;

public class LightBulbControls extends JPanel
{
   private LightBulbPanel bulb;
   private JButton onButton, offButton;
   private Timer timer;
   private int DELAY;
   private JLabel timeLabel;

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sets up the lightbulb control panel.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public LightBulbControls(LightBulbPanel bulbPanel)
   {
      bulb = bulbPanel;

      onButton = new JButton("On");
      onButton.setEnabled(false);
      onButton.setMnemonic('n');
      onButton.setToolTipText("Turn it on!");
      onButton.addActionListener(new OnListener());

      offButton = new JButton("Off");
      offButton.setEnabled(true);
      offButton.setMnemonic('f');
      offButton.setToolTipText("Turn it off!");
      offButton.addActionListener(new OffListener());

      timeLabel = new JLabel("0.0");
      timeLabel.setBackground(Color.white);
      timeLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);

      DELAY = 10;

      timer = new Timer();
      //timer.schedule(new OnListener(), DELAY*1000);

      setBackground(Color.black);
      add(onButton);
      add(offButton);
      add(timeLabel);
   }
   //*****************************************************************
   //  Represents the listener for the On button.
   //*****************************************************************
   private class OnListener implements ActionListener
   {
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Turns the bulb on and repaints the bulb panel.
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
         bulb.setOn(true);
         onButton.setEnabled(false);
         offButton.setEnabled(true);
         bulb.repaint();
      }
   }

   //*****************************************************************
   //  Represents the listener for the Off button.
   //*****************************************************************
   private class OffListener implements ActionListener
   {
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Turns the bulb off and repaints the bulb panel.
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
         bulb.setOn(false);
         onButton.setEnabled(true);
         offButton.setEnabled(false);
         bulb.repaint();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337718/java-swing-timer-countdown/28338476#28338476), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512527/java-updating-existing-stopwatch-code-to-include-countdown/33512781#33512781) (in the opposite direction, but the concept is the same), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082987/what-is-wrong-with-this-timer/21083042#21083042), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795309/how-to-make-the-images-clickable-with-additional-problems/12796462#12796462)

Comment: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272833/multiple-swing-timers-cause-multiple-actions-to-happen/21272994#21272994). Take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: The short answer to your question is, no, don't use `java.util.Timer`, instead, use `javax.swing.Timer`, it's safer to use within Swing as the `ActionListener` is notified within the context of the EDT

Comment: So I've been surfing the web and stuff how to use the timer class and looking at oracle docs. I'm just confused. so basically I Create a Timer object using swing package. then in the constructor I instansiate that object which i named timer with parameters of 10*1000, new OnListener(). then this is the part im confused. so I go into the OnListener class and then make a maybe if statement saying if bulb.on(true) then timer.start() and when timer = to 10 seconds a timerTask switches the image to offbulb?

Comment: No, you call `Timer#start` when you want to start the timer (so when the user clicks the button), when the timer "ticks" it will call the assigned `ActionListener` and you will want to take appropriate action based on the needs of what you are trying to achieve. This best thing is to start a new basic project and play around with it, when you have a better grasp, then you can look at modifying your existing code

Comment: ok, i've slept on the problem and i've been thinking so already have an OffListener for off button On Listener for on button, and now I made an TimeClass that implements actionlistener. I set my JLabel to 10 and the casted the value to a variable. in the TimeClass the action event will probably be like bulb.setOn(true) count--. If you want to see what i've done so far you can. I'm not sure why the code doesn't work though.